# Binding ObervableCollection to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following code that should display some information about ContactLists in a ListBox but there seems to be a problem with the binding as nothing is displayed. What am I missing? Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

**XAML**

```
</Window>
<Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactsTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Text="{Binding ContactListName, Mode=Default}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
      Background="#FFCBD5E6">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <ListBox x:Name="contactsList"
             SelectionMode="Extended"
             Margin="7,8,0,35" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ContactLists}" 
             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ContactsTemplate}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Width="178" 
             SelectionChanged="contactsList_SelectionChanged"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ContactListModel> ContactLists;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        var data = new ContactListDataAccess();
        ContactLists = data.GetContacts();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change ContactLists to be a property for the binding to work correctly:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ContactListModel> ContactLists{get;set;}

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        var data = new ContactListDataAccess();
        ContactLists = data.GetContacts();

    }
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields) for more info.

Comment: In addition to that, it would be great if you would set it to be accessed via a DependencyProperty.

Comment: No need to set it as a DP, since you probably never want to change ContactLists *instance* (only its contents)