# Example for WPF Treeview data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm beginner for C# and WPF.

When I tried to figure out how to bind data to treeview, I find a example in Microsoft learn, the link is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-7.0.

It is a pity in this example only XAML code is provided, for objects there is only description but not code. Please see the picture below for the objects description.

[image]

I code the objects with my limited C# knowledge, as below.

**Objects: ListLeagueList**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Treeview01
{
    public class ListLeagueList : ObservableCollection<League>
    {
        public ListLeagueList() : base()
        {
            Add(new League("League A"));
            Add(new League("League B"));
            Add(new League("League C"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Objects: League**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Treeview01
{
    public class League
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        List<Division> Divisions  = new List<Division>();
        public League(string name) //: base()
        {
            Name = name;
            Divisions.Add(new Division("DivisionA"));
            Divisions.Add(new Division("DivisionB"));
            Divisions.Add(new Division("DivisionC"));
        }
        private League()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Objects: Division**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Treeview01
{
    public class Division
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        List<Team> Teams = new List<Team>();
        public Division(string name) //: base()
        {
            Name = name;
            Teams.Add(new Team("Bear"));
            Teams.Add(new Team("Rocket"));
        }
        private Division()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

**Objects: Team**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Treeview01
{
    public class Team
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Team(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        private Team()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="Treeview01.Window1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="HierarchicalDataTemplate Sample"
      xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Treeview01">
        <DockPanel>
            <DockPanel.Resources>
                <src:ListLeagueList x:Key="MyList"/>
    
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:League}"
                                    ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Divisions}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:Division}"
                                    ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Teams}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Team}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                
            </DockPanel.Resources>
    
            <Menu Name="menu1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <MenuItem Header="My Soccer Leagues"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}}" />
            </Menu>
    
            <TreeView>
                <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}}" Header="My Soccer Leagues" />
            </TreeView>
    
        </DockPanel>
    </Window>
```

**XAML.CS:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Treeview01
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

With the code above, only the first level data is represented, as the picture below.

[image]

Please check and correct my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Divisions` and `Teams` can not be recognized in Xaml, because they are not public properties.

Devisions

```
public List<Division> Divisions { set; get; } = new List<Division>();
```

Teams

```
public List<Team> Teams { set; get; } = new List<Team>();
```

Comment: Many thanks! It's do work properly when I changed the code as your sample.

Furthermore, can I ask why here '{set; get;}' must be used?  As far as I know it will become a property from a field. But why it must be a property in this case?

Comment: Furthermore, in case I want to add a new node to the treeview (add a new league e.g.), via click a button.  Could you show me the code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can add do it like this `(DockPanel.Resources["MyList"] as ListLeagueList)?.Add(new League("Z"));`.. for the first question you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6220585/4108016).. it's just required by binding engine..

Comment: Forget to mention to give `DockPanel` a name in xaml `x:Name="DockPanel"`

Comment: Thanks again for your answer!  

(DockPanel.Resources["MyList"] as ListLeagueList)?.Add(new League("Z")); this is the instance name I don't know how to express.

Comment: ...when I try to add a new object "Division" in collection "Divisions", I've trid the code `((DockPanel01.Resources["MyList"] as League).Divisions).Add(new Division("Division D"));`, but it doesn't work. 

Could you check and correct my code again? Thank you very much!

Comment: Make Divisions an observableCollection instead of List

Comment: Yes, I'd tried to use observableCollection instead of List, but still didn't work. The code can be compiled, but there will be a error happen when I trigger the "add divison" command. The message is: _System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'(... as Treeview01.League) returned null._

Comment: Your code is wrong, because `(DockPanel01.Resources["MyList"] as League)` will return a list of Leagues.. To add a division to the first league, you can do `(DockPanel01.Resources["MyList"] as ListLeagueList)?[0]?.Divisions.Add(new Division("Division D"));`

Comment: ...It seem `[]` is not supported, for the reason of "Cann't apply indexing with[] to an expression of type 'league'".

Comment: No, [] is applied over ListLeagueList, which is a collection, make sure to copy the code from my comment.. I've tried it and it works, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikCfp.png)

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Now it is work properly! I guess that's all my questions for this moment. Thank you very much for your time and patient answer!!