# Two-way binding requires Path or XPath. in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am creating a DataTable with the following function:

```
public DataTable getTable() {

    DataTable T = new DataTable();

    T.Columns.Add("Type / Control", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    T.Columns.Add("Investment cost", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
    T.Columns.Add("Removal cost", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
    T.Columns.Add("Maintainance cost", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
    string name;

    foreach (CatalogueEntry entry in this.CatalogueList) {

        if (entry.type != EntryType.Battery) {
            name = entry.PF_type_elm.Name.GetString();
        } else {
            BatteryCatalogueEntry bce = (BatteryCatalogueEntry)entry;
            name = bce.control.Name;
        }

        DataRow row = T.NewRow();
        row[0] = name;
        row[1] = entry.InstallationCost;
        row[2] = entry.RemovalCost;
        row[3] = entry.MaintenanceCost;

        T.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return T;
}
```

and I set it to a data grid like this:

```
DataTable T = getTable();
this.libraryDataGrid.ItemsSource = T.DefaultView;
```

The first problem is that the first column shows no values (they should be string values)
and when I try to write something in the first colum it gives the "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath" error. The columns marked as double are fine and they are updatable.

I have seen this question being solved by putting {get;set;}  in the data structures but I don't see how that aplies here.

Just in case, the XAML code is:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="libraryDataGrid" Margin="0,0,0,30" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray" Background="{x:Null}"/>
```

There is no binding there.

see: [“Two-way binding requires Path or XPath” when edit wpf datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258860/two-way-binding-requires-path-or-xpath-when-edit-wpf-datagrid)
see: [How do I fix “Two-way binding requires Path or XPath” exception in WPF Datagrids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449689/how-do-i-fix-two-way-binding-requires-path-or-xpath-exception-in-wpf-datagrids?rq=1)

Thanks

Comment: Show us your XAML markup

Comment: markup? do you mean the XAML?

Comment: @user3020849 the **M** in *XAML* stands for *markup*.

Comment: I added the very simple XAML code I use for the datagrid.

Answer (score 2):

By bizarre the solution is, it works:

I changed the name of the first column:

from: `T.Columns.Add("Type / Control", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));`
to `T.Columns.Add("Type or Control", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));`

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why but if you remove the `/` mark from the first rows name(`Type / Control`),you won't get the error anymore.
And if you want to bind that row to `name`,it should be a public property otherwise you can't change it from view.