# Added a column to a Datagrid, crash when editing values in any row though

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatable

I'm dynamically pulling a datatable from a previous window, I want to add a column, that i can edit and reference. Basically to save a Quantity recieved for each row. I've managed to add the column, but when I try to edit the textbox I recieve the error 'Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.'.

From what i've looked at online I think my problem might be that it's not initialized? I can edit any of the already existing columns without an error

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datatable" ItemsSource="{Binding SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl}" />
```

XAML.CS:

```
private void addDataColumn()
{
  DataGridTextColumn QtyRcvd = new DataGridTextColumn();
  QtyRcvd.Header = "QtyRcvd";
  QtyRcvd.Binding = new Binding("QtyRcvd");
  datatable.Columns.Add(QtyRcvd);
}
```

Comment: Without more code it is hard to diagnose your issue - I tried to reproduce it with the code you posted, but could not. Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449689/how-do-i-fix-two-way-binding-requires-path-or-xpath-exception-in-wpf-datagrids)? There, this error is caused by trying to bind to a field instead of a property.

Comment: What does SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl return?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons below might cause your problem.

1. Make sure you have getter and setter for the members of your class.

   public bool Skip { get; set; }
2. Make sure you have no typo in the path of your bindings. Capitalization is important here.
3. If none of the above solve your problem, try to bind it explicitly to "."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the property "QtyRcvd" bind to the new column.

```
QtyRcvd.Binding = new Binding("QtyRcvd");
```

1. Please make sure it bind to a valid property.
2. In order to edit the new column, the property "QtyRcvd" need to have setter.

   ```
   public int QtyRcvd {get;set;} //"get" to display, "set" to edit.
   ```