# DataGrid CheckBox can't be checked

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox

I got a problem with datagrid and DataGridCheckBoxClumn. First of all im creating struct for datagrid items:

```
public struct taxRateFromDatabase
{
    public int rate { get; set; }
    public string mark { get; set; }
    public CheckBox c { get; set; }
}
```

And after that in my class adding columns, bindings etc:

```
    StackPanel tSp = new StackPanel();
    DataGrid taxRateDataGrid = new DataGrid();
    DataGridTextColumn col0 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    DataGridCheckBoxColumn col2 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
    Binding b = new Binding("checkBox");
    b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

    b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

    taxRateDataGrid.Columns.Add(col0);
    taxRateDataGrid.Columns.Add(col1);
    taxRateDataGrid.Columns.Add(col2);

    col0.Binding = new Binding("rate");
    col1.Binding = new Binding("mark");
    col2.Binding = b;

    CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
    c.Content = "a";


    col0.Header = "Stawka";
    col1.Header = "Oznaczenie";
    col2.Header = "Status";



    taxRateDataGrid.Items.Add(new taxRateFromDatabase { rate = 0, mark = "E", c = c });
    taxRateDataGrid.Items.Add(new taxRateFromDatabase { rate = 1, mark = "G", c = c });
```

Problem is that I cant really check/uncheck that checkbox i have just added.
I have tried also without checkbox in struct definition (just empty datagridcheckboxcolumn), but that also doesnt work. Im creating it in class which will return datagrid so i cant really acces xaml.

Any sugestions will be appreciated ;)

Comment: I can't see where you're adding the checkbox to the controls.  Are you doing?

Comment: c = c in taxRateDataGrid (c from class, and = c as checkbox you can see under code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use class instead struct (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields)) and implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) interface in order to get the binding working.

Something like

```
public class TaxRateFromDatabase : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private int _rate;
            public int Rate
            {
                get { return _rate; }
                set { _rate = value; OnPropertyChanged("Rate"); }
            }

            private string _mark;
            public string Mark
            {
                get { return _mark; }
                set { _mark = value; OnPropertyChanged("Mark"); }
            }

            private bool _isChecked;
            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return _isChecked; }
                set { _isChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
            }





            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }
```

and for example

```
DataGrid taxRateDataGrid = new DataGrid();
        DataGridTextColumn col0 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        DataGridCheckBoxColumn col2 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();


        taxRateDataGrid.Columns.Add(col0);
        taxRateDataGrid.Columns.Add(col1);
        taxRateDataGrid.Columns.Add(col2);

        col0.Binding = new Binding("Rate");
        col1.Binding = new Binding("Mark");
        col2.Binding = new Binding("IsChecked");

        col0.Header = "Stawka";
        col1.Header = "Oznaczenie";
        col2.Header = "Status";


        List<TaxRateFromDatabase> list = new List<TaxRateFromDatabase>();


        list.Add(new TaxRateFromDatabase { Rate = 1, Mark = "E", IsChecked = true });
        list.Add(new TaxRateFromDatabase { Rate = 23, Mark = "F", IsChecked = false });

        taxRateDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I used your code, just like u wrote it. So now i guess i shouldnt create new Checkbox, just use DataGridCheckBoxColumn instead?
like that : http://pastebin.com/0qhYWfLp ?
Asking becouse still cant check/uncheck..

Comment: @AdamTruszkowski edit col2.Binding = new Binding("isChecked"); to col2.Binding = new Binding("IsChecked"); at line 14 in your link.

Comment: taxRateDataGrid.Items.Add(new TaxRateFromDatabase { Rate = 1, Mark = "E", IsChecked = true });
that works fine ( i mean after that IsChecked = true) chkbox is checked, but I cant uncech it