# Error when binding WPF combobox ItemsSource to an Array of Strings

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, itemssource

I could not set a combobox's ItemsSource to an Array. I have tried setting the DataContext to the class where the Array is found, and then setting the bindings in XAML

```
 class Car
{
    public string[] makes;
}
```

...

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Car _Car = new Car();
    _Car.makes = new string[]
        {
            "Toyota",
            "Mitsubishi",
            "Audi",
            "BMW"           
        };

    this.DataContext = _Car;
}
```

and then in XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="cars" Grid.Column="0" 
              Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=makes}"/>
```

It doesn't seem to do anything. My cars combobox won't have any items.

I've also tried explicitly assigning

```
cars.ItemsSource= new string[]{
                "Toyota",
                "Mitsubishi",
                "Audi",
                "BMW"           
            };
```

But then I get this error message:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WPF binding doesn't support fields. Make it a property that has a getter and setter

```
class Car
{
    public string[] makes { get; set; }
}
```

Regardless, you do not have to explicitly state `Path`, so this should suffice

```
<ComboBox Name="cars" Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding makes}"/>
```

Comment: wow. it worked, thanks!.. but how could it be, when 'makes' has already been set to 'public', which in my understanding is already accessible by other functions?

Comment: @CarlNathanMier It is accessible, but this is not enough. WPF binding works on the `PropertyDescriptor` model which requires a property. you can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields)

Comment: Thanks, but would you also know why assigning 'cars.ItemsSource= new string[]{
                "Toyota",
                "Mitsubishi",
                "Audi",
                "BMW"           
            };' returns the exception? thanks

Comment: @CarlNathanMier My guess would be that you might set the `ItemsSource` twice, in the xaml `ItemsSource="{Binding makes}"` and in the code-behind, but you should look into the inner exception to get more details ...

Answer (score 3):

In Order for data binding to work correctly, you need a 'Property' to bind to.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox Name="cars" Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding makes}"/>
```

**Code**

```
class Car
{
    public string[] makes { get; set; }
}
```