# How to bind a field to a gauge control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gauge, data-binding

I've added a WPF gauge control from this class https://github.com/JohanLarsson/GaugeBox but I'm not sure how to wire the control up to a field of type double `degreeOutput` declared in the code behind.

My aim is to bind `degreeOutput` to the gauge control and have the values from `degreeOutput` update the gauge accordingly.

The process I followed in setting up the control is:

1)Add the control to the user control's xaml layout and declare the namespace
`xmlns:gauges="clr-namespace:Gauges;assembly=Gauges"`

2)Set the value property to `Value="{Binding degreeOutput}"`

3)Run application, (but the gauge doesn't update in accordance with the
degree readings being output from `degreeOutput`)

Does anyone know what step I'm missing in binding the control to my degree field?

This is the xaml layout for the guage control:

```
    <gauges:Gauge x:Name="Gauge"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Margin="13,18,134,134"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Marker="{Binding Marker}"
                          Maximum="{Binding Max}"
                          Minimum="{Binding Min}"
                          Placement="{Binding Placement}"
                          ShowLabels="{Binding ShowLabels}"
                          ShowMajorTicks="{Binding ShowTicks}"
                          ShowTrack="{Binding ShowTrack}"
                          TickFrequency="{Binding TickFrequency}"
                          Value="{Binding degreeOutput}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <gauges:Gauge.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-89.868"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </gauges:Gauge.RenderTransform>
        <gauges:Gauge.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Red" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.10" Color="Red" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.10" Color="Green" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.90" Color="Green" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.90" Color="Red" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Red" />
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </gauges:Gauge.Background>
    </gauges:Gauge>
```

And the code behind where `degreeOutput` is declared:

```
        private double degreeOutput;
```

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: can you explain the process? So far I've just set the value to my double variable but I'm not sure what to do after that.

Comment: Check the GaugeBox's Vm implementation for Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you can't bind to *fields* in WPF (see the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/842575/4265041)).

Try changing `degreeOutput` into a public property. This will be enough to feed the initial value through into the gauge control.

If you also want changes made by the gauge control to feed back into your property then the class containing the property must also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: In this implementation, the changes will be one way only from `degreeOutput` to the gauge not vice versa.


 So from your answer, I've changed `degreeOutput` to a public property but now the device freezes I'm thinking as a result of changing degreeOutput to a public property: This is the class before I changed which was working:

 http://pastebin.com/JPhuphHe

And this is the class after I changed to a public property which isn't working as it causes the device to freeze, any ideas as to why this change causes the code to freeze?

http://pastebin.com/0E5mbeRw 
http://pastebin.com/7Dq5Smbz

Comment: @BrianJ The short answer is I don't know. Try changing `private double degreeOutput;` to `public double degreeOutput { get; set; }` and remove the `Degrees` property that you created.

Comment: I need to remodel my project to MVVM it seems to set this up properly, thanks for the advice.