# Populate my ListView with item source from class

Tags: wpf, listview, itemsource

I have this `Singleton` that hold my `ObservableCollection<MyData>` as a memeber:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static volatile Singleton instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    public ObservableCollection<MyData> Files { get; private set; }

    private Singleton()
    {
        Files = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Declaration from main form class:

```
ObservableCollection<MyData> Files;
```

And here after the constructor:

```
Files= Singleton.Instance.Files;
```

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" />
```

Now when the user choose files i want to check each file:

```
private static void Check(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(files,
            new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
            },
        file =>
        {
            ProcessFile(file);
        });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }, tokenSource.Token,
       TaskCreationOptions.None,
       TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith
        (t =>
        {

        }
, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
);
}
```

And:

```
private static void ProcessFile(string file)
{
    // Lets assume that i want to add this file into my `ListView`
    MyData data = new .....
    Singleton.Instance.Files.Add(data);
}
```

So after this point when i am add files into my list nothing happenning.

Comment: did you set the `DataContext` of the main form class? E.g. `Files= Singleton.Instance.Files; this.DataContext = this;`

Comment: Yes, after Files = Singleton.Instance.Files;

Comment: Check if there is an TargetInvokationException in `ProcessFile`. Adding items  to an `ObservableCollection<>` must happen in the same thread as the collection is created. So in your case the UI-thread... You can use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Singleton.Instance.Files.Add(data))` to ensure.

Comment: No exception, i also try to use this Application.Current.Dispatcher... and i can see via the dubugger that my list is filled.

Comment: Sure there is no exception? You catch everything without any logging in the code above: `catch (Exception) {}`

Comment: Sure, i am using try catch and there is no exception.

Comment: WPF can't bind to fields. Make your files collection in main form a property...

Comment: What do you mean make your files collection in main form a property ?

Comment: Just add get and set to it: `ObservableCollection<MyData> Files { get; private set;}`

Comment: I think my problem is other, please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688280/bind-my-object-inherit-into-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code above i was able to reproduce the issue you describe.
The problem is that WPF cannot bind to fields, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields) for more details. All you need to do is to change the `ObservableCollection<MyData>` in the code behind of your main form to a property instead of a field.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyData> Files { get; private set; }
```