# Bind my object inherit into ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, bind

I try to binn  my object into `ListView` and this not working, this object is inherit from another so my suspition is maby i try another way or i missing something.
This is all my stuff:

This object represent WiresharkFile, i try to support and several format so every format file have this properties:

1. File name
2. Number of packet
3. Packets sent (my application also sent this packets using Pcap.Net)
4. Duration
5. Speed
6. Progress (percent)

   public abstract class WiresharkFile
   {
       protected string _fileName;
       protected int _packets;
       protected int _packetsSent;
       protected string _duration;
       protected double _speed;
       protected int _progress;

   ```
   public string FIleName
   {
       get { return _fileName; }
       set { _fileName = value; }
   }

   public int Packets
   {
       get { return _packets; }
       set { _packets = value; }
   }

   public int PacketsSent
   {
       get { return _packetsSent; }
       set { _packetsSent = value; }
   }

   public string Duration
   {
       get { return _duration; }
       set { _duration = value; }
   }

   public double Speed
   {
       get { return _speed; }
       set { _speed = value; }
   }

   public int Progress
   {
       get { return _progress; }
       set { _progress = value; }
   }
   ```

   }

This is my list view:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding wiresharkFiles}" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
                            <!-- file name column -->
                            <GridViewColumn Width="485" Header="File name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" />

                            <!-- speed column -->
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="SpeedCell"  Width="130" Header="Speed" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate2}" />

                            <!-- duration column -->
                            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Duration" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}" />

                            <!-- packets column -->
                            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Packets" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Packets, StringFormat={}{0:#,0}}" />

                            <!-- packet sent -->
                            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Packets sent" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PacketsSent, StringFormat={}{0:#,0}}" />

                            <!-- progress column -->
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="ProgressCell"  Width="60" Header="Progress" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And my `Collection` that holds all this objects:

Declaration:

```
ObservableCollection<WiresharkFile> wiresharkFiles;
```

And after the construstor:

```
wiresharkFiles = new ObservableCollection<WiresharkFile>();
this.DataContext = this;
```

Now from my main foram i create new object:

```
WiresharkFile wiresharkFile = new Libpcap("file name");  
wiresharkFile.ReadFileDetails(); // this read the file and count how many packet contain, duration...
wiresharkFiles.Add(wiresharkFile);
```

This `Libpcap` is inherit from `WiresharkFile`:

```
public class Libpcap : WiresharkFile...
```

So after this point my abject is inside this `Collection` but still i cannt see this inside my `ListView`.
I also try to see with try-catch if throw excetion but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
wiresharkFiles = new ObservableCollection<WiresharkFile>();
//this.DataContext = this
this.DataContext = wiresharkFiles;
```