# Binding and Getters & Setters

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Why does `public string name {get; set;}` work when binding, but `public string name;` does not? Why is the getter required when they both return the same string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you can only bind to public *properties* in WPF. The following is a *field* and not a property:

```
public string name;
```

The binding engine only looks for properties when the binding expressions are evaluated using reflection at runtime.

Comment: I believe the answer relates to the fact that one is a field and the other is a property with getters and setters. WPF likely only supports binding on properties to allow for user defined functionality in both the get and set.

Comment: @DanielAtwood That's exactly what mm8 said.

Comment: @DanielAtwood The first one is a property and the second one is a *field* and you can only bind to *properties* as I stated in the answer.

Comment: @Dispersia I apologize. It appears his or her answer changed after posting that.

Comment: @mm8. I know that fact. But why the binding engine only looks for properties. Is there .net source code proving that?

Comment: @Bigeyes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields