# How to bind IsChecked to a ViewModel subclass

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to make a checkbox bind to a subclass of my ViewModel class (without much luck).

In my ViewModel class...

```
public class TestClass
{
   private bool _TestValue;
   public bool TestValue
   {
      get { return _TestValue; }
      set
      {
         _TestValue = value;
         System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("TestValue = " + _TestValue);
      }
   }
}
public TestClass TC;
```

In my ViewModel constructor...

```
TC = new TestClass();
TC.TestValue = false;
```

In my View...

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=TC.TestValue, Mode=TwoWay}">Option 1</CheckBox>
```

My expectation is that when I toggle the checkbox I should see windows popping up that say "TestValue = True" or "TestValue = False", but that doesn't happen. What am I missing?

Comment: That isn't the recommended approach to achieve something like that. You should Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to `TestClass` and then handle that event in your ViewModel.
The code that raises the MessageBox will be in this handler

Comment: As @AgustinMeriles said, implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Look up proper mvvm tutorials. There are tons online. You will only need to implement minor changes to your existing `TestClass`. Btw AFAIK, `System.Windows.MessageBox` doesn't work in WPF. I remember that we used to implement our own dialog controls for this.

Comment: @Ephraim What do you mean `System.Windows.MessageBox` doesn't work in WPF? It works fine, I used it many times for test purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your `TC` public field into property and your binding will work.

```
public TestClass TC { get; }
```

You can learn more about this behavior from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields) post.