# How to connect a list<myClass> with DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, list, datagrid

i have an issue with this task. Can you help me?

```
class FileTAG
{
    public FileInfo file;
}
```

I create a List of FileTAG (it calls checkTag) and i want to show all data content in every node of my list in a datagrid on WPF application. So i do this:

```
grd_lista.ItemsSource = checkTag;
```

but this is what appear.

[File01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR2W4.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: Your `FileTAG.file` has to be a property. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields

Comment: Can you explain more? My FileInfo file is already a property of a class FileTAG

Comment: `FileTAG.file` is a field not a property, you have to write `public FileInfo File { get; set; }`(better use PascalCasing. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions). More about properties and fields see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties / https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property

Comment: Ok, i change my field into a property. But this not change my visualization on DataGrid.

I've add in my class FileTag, the property nomeFile:

    <code>public string nomeFile { get; set;}<code>

in my dataGrid grd_lista appear a new column with the lenght of a string but not the text.

Comment: Please add those changes to your question and also add the xaml portion where your `DataGrid` is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach. In WPF you need to add:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" />
```

where Files is a collection of FileTAG objects.

Answer (score -1):

You can connect list with datagridview :`DataGridViewName.DataSource=listName`
as : `grd_lista.DataSource=...`

Comment: He uses `WPF` not `Windows Forms`

Comment: I'm sorry, you can replace `DataSource` with `Source`

Comment: Still will not work. Neither has `WPF` a `DataGridView` nor does `DataGrid` (what he uses) has a `Source` property