# WPF DataGrid binding certain fields from class not all

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

I want to bind certain fields from class to DataGrid in WPF through DataSource but now there is problem, fields bind properly but there are also fields from class that I don't want how can I prohibit this behavior?

Method where I bind them to DataGrid.

```
string[] tabelaPredmetBinding = { "Naziv", "Kratica", "Ects" };    
//method where I try to bind data to grid

    private void predmet_load()
    {
        DataGridPodatki.Columns.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < tabelaPredmet.Length; i++) {
            DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
            textColumn.Header = tabelaPredmet[i];
            textColumn.Binding = new Binding(tabelaPredmetBinding[i]);
            DataGridPodatki.Columns.Add(textColumn);
        }

        /*foreach (var item in servis.vrniVsePredmete()) {
            DataGridPodatki.Items.Add(item);
        }*/

        DataGridPodatki.ItemsSource = servis.vrniVsePredmete();

    }
```

Class that get's returned from SOAP service

```
[DataContract]
public class Predmet
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Naziv { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Kratica{get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int Ects { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<StudentImaPredmet> studentiImajoPredmet { get; set; }

    public Predmet()
    {
        studentiImajoPredmet = new HashSet<StudentImaPredmet>();
    }

    public Predmet(string naziv, string kratica, int ects)
    {
        Naziv = naziv;
        Kratica = kratica;
        Ects = ects;
    }

}
```

[image: This is what I get, I only want "Naziv","Kratica","ECTS"]

Comment: Turn off auto-generate columns on DataGrid object.

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid has [AutoGenerateColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns) with default value `true` - a value that indicates whether the columns are created automatically.

set it to `false` before assigning ItemsSource:

```
DataGridPodatki.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataGridPodatki.ItemsSource = servis.vrniVsePredmete();
```

also: please see about the difference of properties and fields, and [importance of *properties*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields) in bindings.