# How to bind a ObservableCollection of custom controls to a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, stackpanel

I have a ObservableCollection of custom control objects.

`ObservableCollection<MyStatusBar> MyUIObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyStatusBar>();`

The custom control is a user control like this

`public partial class MyStatusBar : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged`

What is the easiest way that I can bind my list of controls to a stackpanel so they show up. Currently when I bind them nothing shows up. When I add the controls manually to the StackPanel.Children collection they then show up but I want to do it with binding.

Comment: Please, share your binding and xaml code

Comment: @daniel use itemscontrol to bind custom object and  set panel type stackpanel to display the collection of custom objects.

Comment: for binding to work `MyUIObjects` has to be [a public *property*, not *field*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/842575/1506454): `public ObservableCollection<MyStatusBar> MyUIObjects {get;} = new ObservableCollection<MyStatusBar>();`

Comment: also it is a questionable idea to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in a UserControl. use only DependencyProperties - they have built-in notification support - and much more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyStatusBar` shouldn't be a `UserControl` but a POCO:

```
public class MyStatusBar : INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }
```

You could then use an `ItemsControl` to bind to the `ObservableCollection<MyStatusBar>` and define an `ItemTemplate` in where you put the `UserControl` to be rendered for each POCO object:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyUIObjects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyStatusBarUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `ItemsPanelTemplate` specifies the panel - in this case a `StackPanel` - that the `ItemsPresenter` creates for the layout of the items in the `ItemsControl`.

Note that `MyStatusBar` and `MyStatusBarUserControl` are different types. A view model should not create or expose UI elements. It should expose data objects. You are then creating a UI element per data object using the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I receive a 26 error: ` ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type`

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the code snippet.
Replace Itemcontrol with any itemscontrols' like listbox so on otherwise can u still use Itemscontrol

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyUIObjects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: ItemsControl uses vertical virtualizing StackPanel by default. it doesn't make much sense to explicitely assign `<StackPanel/>` to ItemsPanel

Comment: @ash you are correct. This snippet is just an example of usage how to bind observable collection instead of complete solution.