# How to bind Fields to DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row, manual

I am programming UI with WPF for a month. So i am new in this world. This is my first ever post here and my motherlanguage isn't English. So if there is any mistake in my writing, sorry for that.

I have a problem with WPF and I am not able to find a solution for it. I am trying to make completely customizable DataGrid in WPF and I don't want the DataGrid to create columns or rows automatically.
I have an `ObservableCollection` named `Sinif_Tutucu` (means *Class_Holder* in my motherlanguage) which holds classes. These classes have the same Field and Properties, but their values are different. I am creating the columns one by one according to Fields and Properties in these classes. After this I am adding columns to DataGrid manually.

Then I am adding the rows with `ItemsSource` like this.

```
DataGrid_1.ItemsSource = Sinif_Tutucu;
```

This populates only properties in the DataGrid and columns made up of fields remain empty. I have searched this and i guess there is no way to bind Fields to DataGrid. Classes within `Sinif_Tutucu` have thousands of fields. So I can't turn fields to properties and I don't want to code the whole datagrid structure from scratch. Because WPF DataGrid structure offers many useful features which i am currently using. I am able to get Field names and their values or Property names and values. I just need to create each row myself (like columns) and populate their cells one by one with my hand with C#. Or somehow I need to convert these Fields to Properties programmatically. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Binding doesn't work with fields. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/843051/4413054

Comment: Hi. I know binding doesn't work with fields. I have read that post before. I can't change the fields because they are coming form different classes and there is thousands of them. So I can't turn them to property or i can't create struct for them and like you said I can't bind fields. Thats why I have to create rows manually like creating columns and add all values cell by cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your class that you want to show in the datagrid looks like this

```
public class Data
{
    public int Value;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Because you cannot bind fields to `DataGridColumns`, you have to dynamically create the columns and the records. Here is a short snippet which you can use to do that. This method creates new `dynamic` objects in a `List`, which stores the same data as in your `ObservableCollection`. This `List` is set as the new `ItemSource` of your `DataGrid`. This snippet only creates `DataGridTextColumns`. You migth have to modify this solution, if want to use other `DataGridColumns`.

```
private void loadDataGrid()
{
    List<dynamic> dataObjects = new List<dynamic>();
    dynamic dataObject;
    IDictionary<string, object> dataObjectValues;

    var fields = typeof(Data).GetFields();

    foreach (var item in Sinif_Tutucu)
    {
        dataObject = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            dataObjectValues = (IDictionary<string, object>)dataObject;
            dataObjectValues[field.Name] = field.GetValue(item);
        }

        dataObjects.Add(dataObject);
    }

    dataObjectValues = (IDictionary<string, object>)dataObjects[0];

    foreach (var pair in dataObjectValues)
    {
        var binding = new Binding(pair.Key);

        DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = binding, Header = pair.Key }; //You might want to use another DataGridColumn-Type

        dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
    }

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataObjects;
}
```