# Databind properties of a class in ContentView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm trying to achieve what I think is probably quite simple but as I'm new to Xamarin & Databinding I think I'm getting in a spin.
I have a very simple `ContentPage` that just has a Databinding to my viewModel for this page and my `ContentView`, TotalsTemplate.

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:DealsTodayViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <template:TotalsTemplate></template:TotalsTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

My viewmodel has a public property of my class, Totals, which has basic int,string,decimal props.

```
    public class DealsTodayViewModel
    {
        Public string ViewModelPeriod;
        public PeriodTotals Totals;
        public DealsTodayViewModel()
        {
            ViewModelPeriod = "TODAY";
            Totals = new PeriodTotals
            {
                Period = "DAILY",
                ClientServices_Deals_Chicago = 1,
                ClientServices_Deals_Manchester_Na = 1,
                ClientServices_Deals_Manchester_Uk = 1,
                ClientServices_Ramp_Chicago = 1.2m,
                ClientServices_Ramp_Manchester_Na = 1.3m,
                ClientServices_Ramp_Manchester_Uk = 1.4m
        };
    }
}
```

Now in my `TotalsTemplte` `ContentView` I have a `Grid` with following inside.

```
    <Label Text="{***Binding ViewModelPeriod***}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
    <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Label Text="{Binding ***Totals.Period***}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
    </Frame>
```

My String property on the `DealsTodayViewModel` is visible in my `ContentView` but not the `Perod` property from inside my Totals property, am I binding incorrectly to this?

Comment: you an only bind to **public properties**.   `Totals` is not a C# property

Comment: Totals is a public property of type PeriodTotals, my underlying class Jason?

Comment: please lookup the definition of a C# property

Comment: What is Totals then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property

Comment: Please avoid putting tags in title when it is not necessary [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: So this isn't an automatically-implemented property then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does WPF support binding to properties of an object, but not fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields)

Comment: no, it is a field.  A property will have a get/set

Comment: Cheers both, really helps me out.

Comment: I summarized your comments and add an answer there. Can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/), data-binding should binding between `properties` instead of field:

> Data binding is the technique of linking properties of two objects so
> that changes in one property are automatically reflected in the other
> property. Data binding is an integral part of the Model-View-ViewModel
> (MVVM) application architecture.

So the solution is change the fields in your vm to properties:

```
public class DealsTodayViewModel
{
    public string ViewModelPeriod { get; set; }
    public PeriodTotals Totals { get; set; }
    public DealsTodayViewModel()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Refer: [field and property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property)