# Using RelayCommand to add item to ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm practicing MVVM by create a simple `ListView` and a `Button`. When `Button` is clicked, a new item will be added to `ListView`. However my implementation doesn't work. I'm using `RelayCommand` for the `Button`. What did I do wrong?

**XAML**

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="AddButton" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Content="Add Item"  Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
        
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewItems" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle >
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox x:Name="Input" FontSize="15"></TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**ListViewModel**

```
public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> items;

        public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items {
            get
            {
                return this.items;
            }

            set
            {
                if (items != value)
                {
                    items = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(items));
                }
            } 
        }

        #region Constructor
        public ListViewModel()
        {
            AddCommand = new RelayCommand(
                ExecuteCommand);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Button command
        public RelayCommand AddCommand;

        private void ExecuteCommand()
        {
            items.Add(new ItemModel());
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotify
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Main Window**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ListViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: look into [output window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window), binding errors there are the first sign you did something wrong.

Comment: @ASh yes I did.

Comment: @ASh I edited the post. The DataContext is set in the MainWindow class

Comment: @Sinatr Oh I see the binding error. But I did have a ```public RelayCommand AddCommand;``` declared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddCommand` should be a *property*:

```
public RelayCommand AddCommand { get; }
```

Currently it is declared as *field* (no getter).

see [Why does WPF support binding to properties of an object, but not fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields)