# ListBox ItemsSource binding path error. What am I missing?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, .net-5

I've having trouble understanding a `ListBox` `ItemsSource` binding error I'm getting. I followed the details on the Gong WPF.DragDrop GitHub project but I'm getting this error on my binding path:

[image: Application with empty ListBox.]

[image: XAML Binding Failures window in Visual Studio with "Items property not found [...]" error.]

The project [here](https://github.com/steveski/WpfListBoxbindingIssue) is what I'm working on and shows the issue. I've extended a little by using a generic type on my observable item so i can make the `ListBoxItemViewModel` reusable but I found that going without the generic type it still fails.

This is the XAML used for the `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox Width="300px" x:Name="clothingItems" Margin="10px" AllowDrop="True"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
         dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
         dd:DragDrop.DragHandler="{Binding}"/>
```

This is the code for my `ListBoxViewModel`.

```
public class ListBoxViewModel<TItemVm> : IDropTarget
        where TItemVm : class, IDropTargetItemViewModel<TItemVm>
{
    public ObservableCollection<TItemVm> Items = new ObservableCollection<TItemVm>();

    public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        var sourceItem = dropInfo.Data as TItemVm;
        var targetItem = dropInfo.TargetItem as TItemVm;

        if (sourceItem != null && targetItem != null && targetItem.CanAcceptChildren)
        {
            dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Highlight;
            dropInfo.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

    }

    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        var sourceItem = dropInfo.Data as TItemVm;
        var targetItem = dropInfo.TargetItem as TItemVm;

        targetItem.Children.Add(sourceItem);

    }
}
```

`ListBoxViewModel` has a public `ObservableCollection` property called `Items` and an instance is assigned as the DataContext so why wouldn't `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` resolve?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does WPF support binding to properties of an object, but not fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Items` in `ListBoxViewModel<TItemVm>` is a *field*, not a property.

```
public ObservableCollection<TItemVm> Items = new ObservableCollection<TItemVm>();
```

Change the member like below to make it a *property* and enable binding it.

```
public ObservableCollection<TItemVm> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TItemVm>();
```

See [Binding Source Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-source-types) for more information on which binding sources can be used in WPF.