# ObservableCollection doesn't update ListView (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a simple setup so far and want to have a listview showing the recent logs.

This is the mainwindow constructor :

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        var MWViewModel = new ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel();

        DataContext = MWViewModel;

        Tools.Logger.LogEntry("Initialized", "Boot", "Welcome");

        InitializeComponent();

        MWViewModel.updateLogs();

    }
```

The logging works fine.
In the Viewmodel it looks like this :

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Models.LogModel> _logs;
    public ObservableCollection<Models.LogModel> Logs      
    {
        get => _logs;
        set => SetProperty(ref _logs, value);
    }

    public void updateLogs()
    {
        _logs = Tools.Logger.getLogs();
    }
```

The getLogs function also works fine, meaning the _logs have all the logging entries of the database.

The XAML looks like this :

```
                    <ListView x:Name="logs_viw" ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}">
                    <ListView.View >
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Timestamp" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding timestamp}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Program" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding program}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Section" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding section}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="610" Header="Log" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding log}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Finally, the Model looks like this

```
    class LogModel
{
    public string timestamp;
    public string program;
    public string section;
    public string log;
}
```

Quite simple, but it doesn't work so far. The ListView does show "something", it has the correct amount of datarows with empty lines?! What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF doesn't support data binding to fields. Use properties instead.

What you can do is change your class to look like this:

```
class LogModel
{
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Log { get; set; }
}
```

For more info -> [Why does WPF support binding to properties of an object, but not fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields)

Comment: well thanks, didnt know that! It works now like a charm