# Binding in C# (MVVM + WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to show a list box with an image and a string as list box items.
To do so I bind a list of ThemeLayer as ItemsSource and defined an ItemTemplate.

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="DataLayerList" SelectionMode="Extended"
         ItemsSource="{Binding LayersFiltered, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Height="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ThemeLayer are defined as such:

C#

```
public class ThemeLayer
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly string Id;
    public readonly string Type;
    public readonly string ImagePath;
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public ThemeLayer(string name, string id, string type, string image)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
        Type = type;
        ImagePath = image;
    }
}
```

and the list *LayersFiltered* contains object of *ThemeLayer* similar to this:

```
 new ThemeLayer("Place","eb760ca1bb494d2887c5d8c51ccc417a", "image", "ImageLayer16.png")
```

When I run my project then I am getting the list box filled with items, but I cannot see a single one. I only know because hovering over the list reveals the different lines of the list box items.

Looking at XAML Binding Failures I get back that *ImagePath* and *Name* (defined in the ItemTemplate) cannot be found on object of type ThemeLayer, even though the objects in *LayersFiltered* certainly are of type *ThemeLayer* and each of them has a property *Name* and *ImagePath*.

The *ThemeLayer* class and the class defining the list of *ThemeLayer* are both in my Models folder, and *LayersFiltered* is a list object within my ViewModel.

How do I have to define the XAML that I get images and names shown?

One more thing:

The images to be shown in the list box are situated within the project, at a folder *Images*. Is it okay to simply reference the image by its name, as shown above, or does that need to be something along the line of "/Images/filename.png"?

Comment: You can only bind to properties, not fields. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields

Comment: Guys, you are awesome! Thanks for the fast reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to properties rather than fields. Change this...

```
public readonly string Name;
public readonly string Id;
public readonly string Type;
public readonly string ImagePath;
```

to be

```
public string Name { get; }
public string Id { get; }
public string Type { get; }
public string ImagePath { get; }
```

These properties are read only, just like the fields they replace.